# How to automatically reload a tomcat server after a code change in spring without spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am working on a Spring project which has tomcat to run the server. While developing in local, after every code change, I have to stop the server and restart it again manually which takes around 3 minutes and makes the development process very slow. It is an old project so spring boot doesn't seem to work in that.

I am attaching the properties of the project in pom.xml file. I just need to now how can I make this server reload automatically after a code change.

```
<properties>
        <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <maven.war.plugin.version>2.2</maven.war.plugin.version>
        <org.springframework.version>5.0.6.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <org.springframework.integration.version>5.0.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.integration.version>
        <org.springframework.data.version>2.0.7.RELEASE</org.springframework.data.version>
        <org.springframework.amqp.version>1.3.9.RELEASE</org.springframework.amqp.version>
        <org.springframework.security.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.security.version>
        <spring.data.mongo.version>2.0.7.RELEASE</spring.data.mongo.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.11.Final</hibernate.version>
        <jpa.version>2.1.0</jpa.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <json.lib.version>0.8</json.lib.version>
        <jackson.core.version>2.9.5</jackson.core.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>8.0.11</mysql.connector.version>

        <log4j-over-slf4j.version>1.7.32</log4j-over-slf4j.version>
        <jcl-over-slf4j.version>1.7.5</jcl-over-slf4j.version>
        <commons-logging.version>1.1.1</commons-logging.version>
        <commons-lang.version>2.6</commons-lang.version>
        <commons-beanutils.version>1.9.2</commons-beanutils.version>
        <commons-collections.version>3.2</commons-collections.version>
        <commons-io.version>2.6</commons-io.version>
        <commons-fileupload.version>1.2.2</commons-fileupload.version>
        <commons-codec.version>20041127.091804</commons-codec.version>


        <tomcat-servlet-api.version>8.5.29</tomcat-servlet-api.version>
        <tomcat-jdbc.version>8.5.29</tomcat-jdbc.version>
        <jsp-api.version>2.1</jsp-api.version>
        <jstl-impl.version>1.2</jstl-impl.version>
        <slf4j-log4j12.version>1.7.32</slf4j-log4j12.version>
        <logback.version>1.0.9</logback.version>
        <httpclient.version>4.3.3</httpclient.version>
        <httpclient-cache.version>4.3.3</httpclient-cache.version>
        <httpmime.version>4.3.3</httpmime.version>
        <fluent-hc.version>4.3.2</fluent-hc.version>
        <httpcore.version>4.3.3</httpcore.version>
        <hibernate-jpa-2.1-api.version>1.0.0.Final</hibernate-jpa-2.1-api.version>
        <javassist.version>3.17.1-GA</javassist.version>
        <jackson-mapper-asl.version>1.9.8</jackson-mapper-asl.version>
        <cglib.version>2.2.2</cglib.version>

        <lombok.version>1.12.6</lombok.version>
        <aws-java-sdk.version>1.3.14</aws-java-sdk.version>
        <jsoup.version>1.7.2</jsoup.version>
        <maple-client.version>16</maple-client.version>
        <tika-parsers.version>1.3</tika-parsers.version>
        <quartz.version>2.1.7</quartz.version>

        <m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>/</m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>
        <!-- QTI+ related changes -->
        <xmlunit.version>1.5</xmlunit.version>
        <xerces.version>2.11.0</xerces.version>
        <lesscss.maven.plugin.version>1.2.1</lesscss.maven.plugin.version>
        <tomcat8.maven.plugin.version>3.0-r1655215</tomcat8.maven.plugin.version>
    </properties>
```